# facebook lint tool fail to load open graph different between Fetched url and Canonical URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, cdn, akamai

I got this url

//www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874146/marcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%7C_week_5

When you try to te

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasl.com%2Fnasltv%2Fwatchvod%2Fid%2F874146%2Fmarcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%257C_week_5%3Fflash

You get a different cannonical URL
//www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874148/nasl_weekly_rewind_%7C_week_5

This was the url first used for start testing the open graph implementation so is my hipotesys to be something cache related and facebook crawl time out

Has you can see this are the og meta defined
view-source:http://www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874146/marcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%7C_week_5?flash

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/866185/marcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%7C_week_5">
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
 <meta property="og:video:height" content="275" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="486" />

<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.nasl.com/ptvFlash/unifiedplayer/sva_adaptive_omniture_1_5/release/UnifiedPlayerV2.swf?configXML=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasl.com%2Fxml%2Fconfig.xml&clipId=874146&setPlayerType=vod&selectedBandwidth=low&resourceLocalePath=%2FptvFlash%2Funifiedplayer%2Fassets%2Fresources%2F&useInitialSplashScreen=true&splashScreen=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasl.com%2F/javaImages/4b/dd/0,,~12836171,00.jpeg">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.nasl.com/ptvFlash/unifiedplayer/sva_adaptive_omniture_1_5/release/UnifiedPlayerV2.swf?configXML=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.nasl.com%2Fxml%2Fconfig_secure.xml&clipId=874146&setPlayerType=vod&selectedBandwidth=low&resourceLocalePath=%2FptvFlash%2Funifiedplayer%2Fassets%2Fresources%2F&useInitialSplashScreen=true&splashScreen=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.nasl.com%2F/javaImages/4b/dd/0,,~12836171,00.jpeg">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

But is allways taken the content from the URL
//www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874146/marcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%7C_week_5

Another insight is this is behind an Akamai CDN

Does any have any insights on this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: _“Is like the link is allways parsing that url and is ignoring the parameter on the url”_ – this is how a canonical URL is _supposed_ to work; it is specified to tell bots and other clients, “this is the _real_ address of this piece of content”, for example to avoid duplicate content in search engines and tell them what URL they should actually use to link to. So if you specify that canonical URL, but don’t actually _mean_ it to be that – then that’s your mistake, not Facebook’s.

Comment: Yes but the cannonical meta are well defined. is like is not recognize the new url is taking the fisrt url i start using for testing i re write the post so is more clear. Thanks for your comments by the way

Answer (score 0):

Because og:url on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasl.com%2Fnasltv%2Fwatchvod%2Fid%2F874146%2Fmarcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%257C_week_5%3Fflash is http://www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874148/nasl_weekly_rewind_%7C_week_5 . Facebook will use og:url as the canonical url.

Comment: Hi Mate thanks for your help
but if you review view-source:http://www.nasl.com/nasltv/watchvod/id/874146/marcos_senna_nyc_nasl_player_of_the_week_%7C_week_5?flash Your will see that the og:url is well defined facebook is not updating the og value is like is thinking is the first url fetched.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error on the id for the meta URL not a cache problem